# Is there a standard way to check if a requirements.txt has potential security issues?

Tags: malware, python, source-code

Every open code repository has security issues. Attackers can use three ways to sneak malware in:

1. Abuse typos: Create a package with a similar name, but the package is malware
2. Malware + useful code: The library actually provides value, but also contains something malicious
3. Update existing code: Attackers could get access to existing legitimate packages, e.g. (1) finding the credentials of one of the maintainers (2) hacking the package repository itself (3) becoming a maintainer of a smaller package by legitimate "ownership transfer"

For Python, dependencies are often explicitly noted in a `requirements.txt` file. I know two tools to analyze this:

- [`piprot`](https://pypi.org/project/piprot/): Check if packages are outdated
- [`safety`](https://pypi.org/project/safety/): Check if packages are in [`safety-db`](https://github.com/pyupio/safety-db) / known for issues

I would also be interested in size, e.g. I would consider some things "save" when they come from big, well-known companies (e.g. Google, Amazon) or belong to bigger organisations (scipy/numpy, Python Software Foundation) or if they have a lot of contributors on Github (maybe also stars / forks ... I'm not sure how easy it is to drive those numbers up, but at least it would show some activity).

Is there a tool which can check a `requirements.txt` (recursively) and check for low-participation projects which could potentially easily get malware?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: I'm closing this as a product recommendation because you answer your title question in your last line. So, it appears that you want a tool and not a method. The method is as you described. That's a simple python script to write.

Comment: @schroeder Basically only an if-statement, right ;-)

Comment: A recursive search through the repos to get the date or any other metadata of the required libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I personally didn't find any out of the box solution that is free.
For personal projects or local I use https://snyk.io/test/ .

I have good experience with them as they are always up to date.

Answer (score 1):

All my github repos have requirements.txt files in them, and GitHub will email you a warning if there are security issues. (it appears that GitHub will scan any file named requirements.txt anywhere in your repo)

The dependency graph will also display some information.

As a previous commenter mentioned synk which is a nice tool, I found that for python, pyup was nicer as it allowed me to publish the results of the scan for anyone to see.

Hope this helps.